# Set product as featured in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a little bit stuck on how to mark only one product at the time as featured. I have added column in my products table `featured` which accept `0` for normal product and `1` for featured.

There can be only one product as featured with `1`

So I've put in my blade following dropdown which display all products

```
{{ Form::open() }}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title" class="control-block">Assign Product as Featured:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="featured">       
            @foreach($products as $featured)                
                <option value="{{ $featured->product_id }}" {{ $featured->featured == 1 ? "selected" : ""}}>{{ $featured->title }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
</div>   
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Make Product Featured</button>        
{{ Form::close() }}

<p>Current Featured Product: <strong>@if($featured->featured == 1){{ $featured->title }}@endif</strong></p>
```

So like this I show all products in dropdown from where admin can select another one and mark as featured. Already market current product in dropdown.

This is what I've put in the controller

```
public function products() {
    $products = Product::all();
    return View::make('site.admin.products', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}

public function featuredProduct($productId) {

    $product = Product::where('product_id', $productId)->first();
    if (!$product) {
        App::abort(404);
    }

    $product_featured = Input::get('featured', $product->featured);
    $product->featured = $product_featured;
    $product->save();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/products');
}
```

And route

```
Route::get ('/admin/products', ['uses' => 'AdminController@products', 'before' => 'admin']);
Route::post ('/admin/products/{productId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@featuredProduct', 'before' => 'admin']);
```

How exactly I can make logic in the controller so to update product which I'm select in dropdown to `1` and current to `0` in database?

Currently the error is

> production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should be opened as:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => '/admin/products/feature', 'method' => 'post']) }}
```

And your route should be as:

```
Route::post('/admin/products/feature', ['uses' => 'AdminController@featuredProduct', 'before' => 'admin']);
```

And you can write your logic as:

```
public function featuredProduct() {
    $product_featured_id = Input::get('featured');

    $product = Product::where('product_id', $product_featured_id)->firstOrFail();

    Product::where('featured', 1)->update(['featured' => 0]); // this will make all product of featured 0

    $product->featured = 1;
    $product->save();
    return Redirect::to('/admin/products');
}
```

Comment: Thank's but I'm getting error `ErrorException: Undefined variable: productId in` on this line: `$product = Product::where('product_id', $productId)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: That's way is updating correctly. Just do you have any idea why after changing the product this line doesn't show current product anymore `<p>Current Featured Product: <strong>@if($featured->featured == 1){{ $featured->title }}@endif</strong></p> `

Comment: Try it like this `<p>Current Featured Product: <strong>{{ $products->where('featured', 1)->first() ? $products->where('featured', 1)->first()->title : '' }}</strong></p>`

Comment: Got `production.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\PlainDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given`

Comment: Check this https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/3z67e9/getting_an_error_that_ive_never_seen_before/

Comment: It says "Switch PHP versions from 7 to 5. And then you should see the real error."

Comment: Ah.. there is no way to make this :(

Comment: Then remove the line `$products->where('featured', 1)`, it may be causing the problem and try to debug it.

Comment: I think the problem is `$products` because it is holding all products or I'm wrong? I've tried to remove it like this `<p>Current Featured Product: <strong>{{ $products->where('featured', 1)->first()->title }}</strong></p>` but error is same

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the form action

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/products/' . $product_id)) }}
```

but I feel something is missing here

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's missing the logic in the control which should switch featured from 0/1 and only one product to be with 1.